# mysql select statement by group with minimum number of recordsets

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm not sure if this will work with a single mysql statement, but this is what I'm trying to achieve:

We are storing user's answers for a variable number of online quizes in *tbl_results*. Each online quiz has a variable number of questions. Each question has a variable number of answers, of which only one is correct.

Here is our *tbl_results* with some sample entries

```
id | quiz_id | user_id | question_id | answer_id | correct
1    2         3         1             1           0
2    2         3         2             2           1
3    2         3         3             3           1

4    2         4         1             1           1
5    2         4         2             2           1
6    2         4         3             3           1

7    2         5         1             1           1
8    2         5         2             2           1
9    2         5         3             3           1

10   2         6         1             1           1
11   2         6         2             2           1
```

`$number_of_questions` tells us how many questions have to be answered correctly in order to win the quiz currently in question.

How do we find out how many users have won quiz number 2 when `$number_of_questions = 3` ? In this case, it would be `user_ids` 4 & 5.

This is what we've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_results WHERE quiz_id = 2 AND CORRECT = 1 GROUP BY user_id
```

How would we adapt this to take account of `$number_of_questions` ...?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: so winning means all correct = 1 for each question ?

Comment: @Abhik: yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HAVING clause:-

```
SELECT quiz_id, user_id, correct, COUNT(*) AS correct_answers
FROM tbl_results 
WHERE quiz_id = 2 
AND CORRECT = 1 
GROUP BY quiz_id, user_id, correct
HAVING correct_answers = 3
```

Note that your GROUP BY in the original query is a bit dubious, and which rows values are brought back for the columns not in the GROUP BY clause are undefined.